# Calculating a point on an ellipse

Tags: math, trigonometry, ellipse

Say I have two points A and B positioned on the circumference of an ellipse, and they form an angle X from the center point.  Now say that point A is moved to a new point C.  How can I calculate the new point for B such that the angle X remains constant?  Pointers to code of some kind would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming question till you work out the geometry part. Is it homework? Tag it as such. By the way, do you know polar coordinates?

Comment: Hi jorgeca, This isn't homework, it's for an application I'm working on.  My math is pretty rusty but I'm reading up on polar coordinates again now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use the polar form of an ellipse where the angle is measured from the ellipse centre??? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center From this equation, if you know the value of the angle between A and B (say theta), and you know the value of central angle of the new point C (say phi), then your required point D can be calculated from this polar form using an angle (theta + phi)